# MySQL: Select rows that have only unique values except for a column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my situation: I have a table which duplicated values are valid (except by the ID field), and I'd like to retrieve only unique values.

For instance, if I have the registers:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
| ID | SATELLITE_ID | ATT_TYPE_ID | TIME | ROLL | PITCH | YAW |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
|  1 |            1 |           1 | 2012 |  1.0 |   2.0 | 1.3 |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
|  2 |            1 |           1 | 2012 |  1.0 |   2.0 | 1.3 |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
|  3 |            1 |           1 | 2011 |  1.0 |   2.0 | 1.3 |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
```

I'd like to retrieve just 2 and 3 (ID 1 and 2 are "equal", and 3 has different TIME).

Here it is the table structure

```
mysql> describe attitude;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| SATELLITE_ID | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ATT_TYPE_ID  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| TIME         | varchar(4)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ROLL         | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| PITCH        | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| YAW          | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Thx.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that any of the non-key column values can change? Also, which column(s) are you selecting in your query?

Comment: A thousand registers is literally nothing to a database engine.

Comment: I'd like to retrieve the entire register (all columns except id), and I have a large database, so performence is an issue (I deleted the previous post due a mistake, so I'm copying it here and changing the number of registers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the `max()` aggregate to the `ID` column and then `GROUP BY` the rest:

```
select max(id) id, SATELLITE_ID, ATT_TYPE_ID, TIME, Roll, Pitch, yaw
from attitude
group by SATELLITE_ID, ATT_TYPE_ID, TIME, Roll, Pitch, yaw
order by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d6b4/4)

Result:

```
| ID | SATELLITE_ID | ATT_TYPE_ID | TIME | ROLL | PITCH | YAW |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |            1 |           1 | 2012 |    1 |     2 |   1 |
|  3 |            1 |           1 | 2011 |    1 |     2 |   1 |
```

Comment: This is the way to go if OP needs to include the ID column in his/her query.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SATELLITE_ID, ATT_TYPE_ID, TIME, ROLL, PITCH, YAW
FROM ATTITUDE
```

Comment: what if OP needs the column `ID` too?

Comment: Then bluefeet's answer would be the best.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select SATELLITE_ID, ATT_TYPE_ID, TIME, ROLL, PITCH, YAW 
from ATTITUDE
group by SATELLITE_ID, ATT_TYPE_ID, TIME, ROLL, PITCH, YAW
```

or you can use `distinct`

```
select distinct SATELLITE_ID, ATT_TYPE_ID, TIME, ROLL, PITCH, YAW 
from ATTITUDE
```

Comment: what about the performance of DISTINCT? Is it so worst than simple SELECT?

Comment: @EtoreMarcariJr. Yes, `distinct` is worse than simple select (without `group by`) because the DB engine has to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(ID) from attitude
  group by SATELLITE_ID, ATT_TYPE_ID, TIME, ROLL, PITCH, YAW;
```

This arbitrarily groups by differing values of SATELLITE_ID, ATT_TYPE_ID, TIME, ROLL, PITCH, and YAW.  If you left out some of these fields, that only means there will potentially be less groups, having fewer reasons to differ from one another.