# Mysql - Select only rows where column has unique value

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

The closest thing I found to what I am looking for is, so I will use it as an example

[MySQL: Select rows that have only unique values except for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606846/mysql-select-rows-that-have-only-unique-values-except-for-a-column)

Given this dataset

```
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
| ID | SATELLITE_ID | ATT_TYPE_ID | TIME | ROLL | PITCH | YAW |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
|  1 |            1 |           1 | 2012 |  1.0 |   2.0 | 1.3 |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
|  2 |            1 |           1 | 2012 |  1.0 |   2.0 | 1.3 |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
|  3 |            1 |           1 | 2011 |  1.0 |   2.0 | 1.3 |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
```

I would like to return only

```
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
| ID | SATELLITE_ID | ATT_TYPE_ID | TIME | ROLL | PITCH | YAW |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
|  3 |            1 |           1 | 2011 |  1.0 |   2.0 | 1.3 |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------+-------+-----+
```

because it is the only unique row

Is this possible with mysql?

Comment: Note that in most case it is a very bad idea to have duplicates in your table. You would be better to add a field "OCCURENCES".

Comment: @AntoinePinsard . . . They are not duplicates.  The ids are different.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I meant excluding the ID. Unless the rows don't represent the same object at all and are legitimate to have their own ID  (for foreign keys for instance).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    SATTELLITE_ID, 
    ATT_TYPE_ID, 
    TIME, 
    ROLL, 
    PITCH, 
    YAW 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY 
    SATTELLITE_ID, 
    ATT_TYPE_ID, 
    TIME, 
    ROLL, 
    PITCH, 
    YAW 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

use `group by` with `having count(*) = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM temptbl 
GROUP BY satellite_id, att_type_id, time, roll, pitch, yaw 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```